Ping from eth0 to eth1
My computer has two network interfaces eth0 and eth1 connected directly with an Ethernet cable. I want to test if these adapters are broken. So, I run
# ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.1
# ifconfig eth1 192.168.0.2
# ping -I eth0 192.168.0.2

But this does not work, regardless of the status of the adapters and cable.
How to configure the machine such that I can ping from eth0 to eth1 if they are directly connected and cannot do so if the cable is removed?

ip link show would tell you if cable is plus/unplug.

Am I missing something? Why not ping to those addresses from another machine on the network?
If the addresses were on different subnets and you had your routing set up correctly, you could tell if the cable is missing by trying a ping to an external address on both subnets.
From that one machine, it is going to be tough (like impossible) to tell if a cable is connected if you don't try to access other machines.  The address is in the port, not in the cable.
